# Maximization over minimum function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem. Suppose we are given $p_r^i \in [0,1]$ for $r={1,2,...,N}$ and $i={1,2}$ such that $\sum_{r=1}^N p_r^i =1$ for i={1,2}. We want to find $x_r \in [0,1]$ and $y_r \in [0,1]$, $r={1,2,...,N}$ that maximize

$\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^N (x_k + y_l + min\{ 1-x_k, y_k,1-y_l,x_l\})p_k^1 p_l^2$

subject to
$\sum_{r=1}^N x_r =1$,$\sum_{r=1}^N y_r =1$.

Possibly we can rewrite the problem as follows:
find $x_r \in [0,1]$ and $y_r \in [0,1]$, $r={1,2,...,N}$ that maximize

$\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^N (x_k + y_l + z_{kl})p_k^1 p_l^2$

subject to

$\sum_{r=1}^N x_r =1$,$\sum_{r=1}^N y_r =1$.

$z_{kl} \leq 1-x_k$ for $k =1,2,...,N$

$z_{kl} \leq y_k$ for $k =1,2,...,N$

$z_{kl} \leq 1-y_l$ for $l =1,2,...,N$

$z_{kl} \leq 1-x_l$ for $l =1,2,...,N$

Any idea for finding optimal solution as function of the parameters involved in the problem?

Comment: Is there a particular context behind this problem? You can always solve it with integer programming (after linearization of the problem).

Comment: I didn't get your meaning by particular context. About the solution approach you suggested, can you explain more?

Comment: What I meant was where does this problem come from? Are you familiar with integer programming?

Comment: I just modeled a part of a problem on which I am working as this optimization problem. Regarding inter programming, I somewhat familiar, but not that much. So I think studying integer programming should be starting point. Thanks

Comment: @Kuifje As you suggested, I edited my question. Any idea how I can find the solution?

Comment: Doing it by hand is probably impossible. There are many modeling languages and solvers out there. My personal favorite: PuLP (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP). With Python, many examples available, very flexible.

Comment: @Kuifje Thanks for your response. I saw some of the example. Is this solver able to solve it parametrically? I mean as a function $p_r^i$s.

Comment: No, you have to give numerical values to all parameters. It is a numerical solver and not a symbolic one.